# Proper way of inverting matrix with so small elements as 1e-20

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am generating matrix which is symmetric, and the magnitude of its elements depend on the length scale of the problem I am dealing with. Typically the matrix is 9x9, but 6x6 version could be also used.

One example of the matrix is like this

```
// A
2.8538093853e-21 7.1747731778e-22 7.1747731778e-22 7.9791996325e-22 7.9791996325e-22 3.0550862084e-22
7.1747731778e-22 2.8538093853e-21 7.1747731778e-22 7.9791996325e-22 3.0550862084e-22 7.9791996325e-22
7.1747731778e-22 7.1747731778e-22 2.8538093853e-21 3.0550862084e-22 7.9791996325e-22 7.9791996325e-22
7.9791996325e-22 7.9791996325e-22 3.0550862084e-22 7.1747731778e-22 3.0550862084e-22 3.0550862084e-22
7.9791996325e-22 3.0550862084e-22 7.9791996325e-22 3.0550862084e-22 7.1747731778e-22 3.0550862084e-22
3.0550862084e-22 7.9791996325e-22 7.9791996325e-22 3.0550862084e-22 3.0550862084e-22 7.1747731778e-22
```

It contains quite small values (order of 1e-22), and based on Numpy, their determinants and condition numbers are like this

```
cond 18.552692061099496
det  8.466833864265427e-127
```

So the condition number is not that bad, but the determinant is very very small. So I expected Numpy will have hard time inverting this giving some random solution depending on its internal tolerance for its numerical scheme for matrix inversion.

And as a very naive approach to improve this situation, I simply scaled this matrix by a certain value (Here, I took 1.3972450422e+21).

```
// A2
3.9874710151e+00 1.0024916252e+00 1.0024916252e+00 1.1148897128e+00 1.1148897128e+00 4.2687040583e-01
1.0024916252e+00 3.9874710151e+00 1.0024916252e+00 1.1148897128e+00 4.2687040583e-01 1.1148897128e+00
1.0024916252e+00 1.0024916252e+00 3.9874710151e+00 4.2687040583e-01 1.1148897128e+00 1.1148897128e+00
1.1148897128e+00 1.1148897128e+00 4.2687040583e-01 1.0024916252e+00 4.2687040583e-01 4.2687040583e-01
1.1148897128e+00 4.2687040583e-01 1.1148897128e+00 4.2687040583e-01 1.0024916252e+00 4.2687040583e-01
4.2687040583e-01 1.1148897128e+00 1.1148897128e+00 4.2687040583e-01 4.2687040583e-01 1.0024916252e+00
```

And its condition number and determinant are

```
cond 18.552692061099485
det  6.300231416456931
```

Now, obviously the condition number and the determinant looks normal.

But what I cannot get at this moment is that the results from both cases are not that different in their quality. The inverted matrix values are very similar, and the A*invA shows a similar deviation (~1e-16) from the identity matrix.

```
inv(A)
6.4337397752e+20 -2.7166291469e+18 -2.7166291469e+18 -5.6175766999e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 2.1049115695e+20
-2.7166291469e+18 6.4337397752e+20 -2.7166291469e+18 -5.6175766999e+20 2.1049115695e+20 -5.6175766999e+20
-2.7166291469e+18 -2.7166291469e+18 6.4337397752e+20 2.1049115695e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 -5.6175766999e+20
-5.6175766999e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 2.1049115695e+20 2.9200923433e+21 -4.3031775290e+20 -4.3031775290e+20
-5.6175766999e+20 2.1049115695e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 -4.3031775290e+20 2.9200923433e+21 -4.3031775290e+20
2.1049115695e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 -4.3031775290e+20 -4.3031775290e+20 2.9200923433e+21

inv(A2)*fnorm
6.4337397752e+20 -2.7166291469e+18 -2.7166291469e+18 -5.6175766999e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 2.1049115695e+20
-2.7166291469e+18 6.4337397752e+20 -2.7166291469e+18 -5.6175766999e+20 2.1049115695e+20 -5.6175766999e+20
-2.7166291469e+18 -2.7166291469e+18 6.4337397752e+20 2.1049115695e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 -5.6175766999e+20
-5.6175766999e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 2.1049115695e+20 2.9200923433e+21 -4.3031775290e+20 -4.3031775290e+20
-5.6175766999e+20 2.1049115695e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 -4.3031775290e+20 2.9200923433e+21 -4.3031775290e+20
2.1049115695e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 -5.6175766999e+20 -4.3031775290e+20 -4.3031775290e+20 2.9200923433e+21
```

```
check A*invA
1.0000000000e+00 -1.9428902931e-16 -2.7755575616e-17 -5.5511151231e-17 5.5511151231e-17 -5.5511151231e-17
-2.7755575616e-17 1.0000000000e+00 -5.5511151231e-17 -2.7755575616e-17 -5.5511151231e-17 0.0000000000e+00
1.6653345369e-16 0.0000000000e+00 1.0000000000e+00 2.7755575616e-17 5.5511151231e-17 0.0000000000e+00 
1.1102230246e-16 3.3306690739e-16 0.0000000000e+00 1.0000000000e+00 1.6653345369e-16 5.5511151231e-17 
-2.2204460493e-16 0.0000000000e+00 2.2204460493e-16 1.1102230246e-16 1.0000000000e+00 1.1102230246e-16 
0.0000000000e+00 3.3306690739e-16 0.0000000000e+00 -2.7755575616e-17 0.0000000000e+00 1.0000000000e+00 

check A2*invA2
1.0000000000e+00 -2.7755575616e-17 -1.1102230246e-16 4.1633363423e-17 6.9388939039e-17 2.7755575616e-17 
-2.7755575616e-17 1.0000000000e+00 5.5511151231e-17 0.0000000000e+00 -2.7755575616e-17 0.0000000000e+00 
5.5511151231e-17 0.0000000000e+00 1.0000000000e+00 0.0000000000e+00 -1.1102230246e-16 -5.5511151231e-17 
-8.3266726847e-17 -1.1102230246e-16 0.0000000000e+00 1.0000000000e+00 2.7755575616e-17 5.5511151231e-17 
-1.1102230246e-16 0.0000000000e+00 2.2204460493e-16 -5.5511151231e-17 1.0000000000e+00 0.0000000000e+00 
-2.2204460493e-16 -7.2164496601e-16 -2.2204460493e-16 8.3266726847e-17 1.1102230246e-16 1.0000000000e+00
```

While 1e-16 order of difference could be regarded as negligible, but I am worrying because they have signs. If this kind of error results in the changes of the signs in the inverted matrix elements, and I would get an inversely directed force in my code. Would there be anything that I can do in this  matrix inversion?

Maybe my problem is in the first place ill-posed, so there is essentially nothing I can do about?

Here is the full python code I used here

```
import numpy as np

def printA(A, n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            print("{:.10e}".format(A[i,j]), end=" ")

        print("")

A = np.array([[2.8538093853e-21, 7.1747731778e-22, 7.1747731778e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22],
              [7.1747731778e-22, 2.8538093853e-21, 7.1747731778e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.9791996325e-22],
              [7.1747731778e-22, 7.1747731778e-22, 2.8538093853e-21, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 7.9791996325e-22],
              [7.9791996325e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.1747731778e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 3.0550862084e-22],
              [7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.1747731778e-22, 3.0550862084e-22],
              [3.0550862084e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.1747731778e-22]])

print("A - cond / det")
printA(A,6)
print("cond {}".format(np.linalg.cond(A)))
print("det  {}".format(np.linalg.det(A)))
#fnorm = 2.7944900844667493e+20
fnorm = 2.7944900844667493e+21 / 2.
A2 = A*fnorm
print("\nA2 = fnorm * A - cond / det")
print("fnorm {:.10e}".format(fnorm))
printA(A2,6)
print("cond {}".format(np.linalg.cond(A2)))
print("det  {}".format(np.linalg.det(A2)))

print("\ninv(A)")
printA(np.linalg.inv(A),6)

print("\ninv(A2)*fnorm")
printA(np.linalg.inv(A2)*fnorm,6)

print("\ncheck A*invA")
printA(np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(A),A),6)

print("\ncheck A2*invA2")
printA(np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(A2),A2),6)
```

Comment: Use `@`, `dot` or `matmul`  for matrix multiplication.

Comment: @hpaulj, and using that solves any of my issue? While I used matmul in the code.

Comment: I don't really see the issue. You have a matrix that is well conditioned. And get a result that is consistent (with a 1e-16 error for a identity matrix). What is the issue?
Your scaling is a correct method if the matrix is well conditioned with very small values (tho, for 1e-22, it is not really needed. By scaling up the matrix, and then scaling up the invert, you are doing more or less the same as keeping track of an offset in exponents. Which is exactly what exponent in floating point numbers would implicitly do anyway. As long as you don't reach the limit.

Comment: But 1e-22*1e-16 (typical error in your matrix inversion times magnitude of your initial matrix) is 1e-38 ; that is well over the limit. Anyway, you saw that yourself, since you see that the deviation in `A*inv(A)` is roughly the same as the one in `α.(A@inv(αA))`. And that error is similar to the one you would get from any invertible 6x6 matrix. The fact that the error have sign doesn't matter (on the contrary: it would be worrying if errors on elements where all in the same direction!) since it is sign on negligible numbers

Comment: I feel that your worrying comes from the fact that in your problem 1e-15 is not a small number. But 1e-15 is not a small number when it comes to `A` values (whatever they are; you said nothing about it, except that you drop the word "force" once) but it is a small number when it comes to `A@inv(A)`. So maybe you want to roll back and explain your problem, and what you want to do with your matrix, and where they come from. But as is, with what you explained, I fail to see any issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error somewhere in your code. I cannot reproduce the issue:

```py
>>> A = np.array([[2.8538093853e-21, 7.1747731778e-22, 7.1747731778e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22],              [7.1747731778e-22, 2.8538093853e-21, 7.1747731778e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.9791996325e-22],
              [7.1747731778e-22, 7.1747731778e-22, 2.8538093853e-21, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 7.9791996325e-22],              [7.9791996325e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.1747731778e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 3.0550862084e-22],
              [7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.1747731778e-22, 3.0550862084e-22],              [3.0550862084e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 7.9791996325e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 3.0550862084e-22, 7.1747731778e-22]])

>>> np.linalg.inv(A*1e22).round(4)

array([[ 0.0643, -0.0003, -0.0003, -0.0562, -0.0562,  0.021 ],
       [-0.0003,  0.0643, -0.0003, -0.0562,  0.021 , -0.0562],
       [-0.0003, -0.0003,  0.0643,  0.021 , -0.0562, -0.0562],
       [-0.0562, -0.0562,  0.021 ,  0.292 , -0.043 , -0.043 ],
       [-0.0562,  0.021 , -0.0562, -0.043 ,  0.292 , -0.043 ],
       [ 0.021 , -0.0562, -0.0562, -0.043 , -0.043 ,  0.292 ]])
```

Comment: Ah, it seems that there had been some error in tabs or newline during copy & paste. I edited, and I checked it works after copy & paste. And yes, your `round(4)` answer is close to what I got from the Numpy, but I wonder if there is any way to improve the precision by normalization etc?

Comment: "While 1e-16 order of difference could be regarded as negligible" It is negligible. You can manually set all values below the threshold to zero if you worry about the signs. Numeric computations are not precise. There is always a certain level of error, you can't do anything about it.